# Iterate over files in a folder to create numpy array

Tags: arrays, file, text, numpy

this is my first posting and I am really new to programming - 
I have a folder with some files that I want to process and then create a numpy array with the values I need I do:

```
listing = os.listdir(datapath)
my_array=np.zeros(shape=(0,5))
for infile in listing:
    dataset = open(infile).readlines()[1:]
    data = np.genfromtxt(dataset, usecols=(1,6,7,8,9))
    new_array = np.vstack((my_array, data))
```

and although I have 2 files in listing (datapath folder) the new_array array overwrites the data and gives me only the values of the second file
any ideas?
thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, the solution to your problem is simply that you need to vstack it to "my_array" not to a new one.

Just replace the last line with this one and it should work:

```
my_array = np.vstack((my_array, data))
```

However, I do not think this is the most efficient way to do it. Since you know how many files are in that folder, just predefine the size of the array and fill its content.

Comment: thanks HyperCube  - that works fine (and makes me feel idiot on how simple it was) -

Comment: I actually tried to predefine an array (np.zeros) but then I failed to fill it in properly - I was either appending/adding rows, or replacing the whole array with a new one...

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you need to do to read all files in a numpy array from a specific folder. I have a folder `test` containing only `.txt` files. My following `file.py` is in the same `test` folder along with all `.txt` files. Each `.txt` file contains a 4x4 matrix/array. After running the script the obtained `matrices` will be a numpy array of [Nx4x4].

```
import numpy as np
from glob import glob

def read_all_files():
   file_names = glob('test/*')
   arrays = [np.loadtxt(f) for f in file_names]
   matrices = np.concatenate(arrays)
```

Comment: if you have a Python list of ndarrays, then you can also call `np.array(arrays)` instead of concat