# extract specific rows in 100 text files in a folder and concatenate these rows of data in a new text file

Tags: python-3.6

How can I extract data in the same way for all text files and combine all of data in a new text file.

I have a folder containing 100 text files with same name structure "S11_M0978-02MS.tif_batch_CDAQQ.txt". And I have extracted all data except first 54 rows in one text files.

All text files includes: 54 rows of strings and the rest is data.

The following is a reference for a text file:

```
[BKM]  
BKM Score = 95  
FILM Warnings = 0  
Edge Detection Warnings = 0  
PSD Fitting Warnings = 0  
[Data]  
    A               B                 C               
-3.8100387  -3.6444700  -4.0741457              
-6.3324452  -2.9988374  -2.6750958  
-3.6361003  -3.4405252  -3.8873997              
-2.8619325  -2.5122818  -2.6663287  
-3.5414995  -3.4363713  -3.7858199              
-6.3302993  -2.7874733  -2.4967888  
-3.4759179  -3.4262204  -3.7153944          
-6.3297628  -2.7358548  -2.4828637
```

The following is how I extract data from one text file:

```
    data = np.genfromtxt( "/Python/S06_M015802MS.tif_batch_CDAQQ.txt", 
    skip_header = 54)
```

I want to extract data in the same way for all text files and combine all of data in a new text file.

Like that:

```
-3.8100387  -3.6444700  -4.0741457      
-2.9226281  -6.3324452  -2.9988374        
-3.6361003  -3.4405252  -3.8873997     --from text 1    
-2.7892024  -6.3308358  -2.8619325       
-3.5414995  -3.4363713  -3.7858199              
-6.3302993  -2.7874733  -2.4967888         
-3.4759179  -3.4262204  -3.7153944     --from text 2                     
 -6.3297628 -2.7358548  -2.4828637          
                    .  
                    .  
                    .
```

Comment: Here is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260907/iterate-over-files-in-a-folder-to-create-numpy-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may search for files by name template. Then use `concatenate` to join data, like:

```
from os import listdir
import os.path
import re
import numpy as np

path = "/Python/"
filePaths = [os.path.join(path,filename) for filename in listdir(path) if re.match(r"^.*tif_batch.*\.txt$", filename)]

data = np.concatenate([np.genfromtxt(f, skip_header = 54) for f in filePaths])
```

If you need to save the output data, you may use:

```
outFile=open(os.path.join(path,'concatenated.txt'),'w')

np.savetxt(outFile, ["""\
[BKM]  
BKM Score = 95  
FILM Warnings = 0  
Edge Detection Warnings = 0  
PSD Fitting Warnings = 0  
[Data]  
    A               B                 C     """ ], fmt='%s')

np.savetxt(outFile, data, fmt='%.7f')
outFile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! It works for me. And may I ask how I can get a new text file in the same folder containing all data?